# Ruby on Rails Error: Couldn't find Status with 'id'=/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got this Nested Resources Error like below:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in FlocksController#index
Couldn't find Status with 'id'=/
```

I don't know where my mistake is but whenever I try to access the index view of the nested resource, I get that error.

Here is my code:

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'public#index'
  
  resources :statuses do 
    resources :flocks
  end

  resources :expenses
  resources :incomes

  # devise_for :users
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }

  get 'dashboard', to: 'public#dashboard'
  get 'financial', to: 'public#financial'
  get 'production', to: 'public#production'

  
  mount ReportsKit::Engine, at: '/'
  
end
```

**Flocks Controller:**

```
class FlocksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_flock, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :set_status

  # GET /flocks or /flocks.json
  def index
    @flocks = @status.flocks.all
  end

  # GET /flocks/1 or /flocks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /flocks/new
  def new
    @flock = @status.flocks.build
  end

  # GET /flocks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /flocks or /flocks.json
  def create
    @flock = @status.flocks.build(flock_params)

    if @flock.save
      redirect_to [@status, @flock], notice: "Flock was successfully created."
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /flocks/1 or /flocks/1.json
  def update
    if @flock.update(flock_params)
      redirect_to [@status, @flock], notice: "Flock was successfully updated."
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /flocks/1 or /flocks/1.json
  def destroy
    @flock.destroy
      redirect_to [@status, :flocks], notice: "Flock was successfully destroyed." 
  end

  private

    def set_flock
      @flock = @status.flocks.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_status
      @status = Status.find(params[:status_id])
    end

    def flock_params
      params.require(:flock).permit(:batch_no, :date_in, :expected_retirement_date, 
                                    :flock_type, :source, :flock_stored, :initial_stock, 
                                    :current_stock, :age, :notes
                                  )
    end
end
```

**Flock Model**

```
class Flock < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :incomes
  has_many :expenses
  
  belongs_to :status

  def left_stock
    initial_stock - current_stock
  end
 
end
```

**Status Model**

```
class Status < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :flocks, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

**Flocks Index view**

```
<%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2 text-center mt-2">
    <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mt-5">
    <h1 class="display-6">Flocks</h1>
    <%= link_to 'New Flock', new_status_flock_path(@status), class: 'btn btn-primary'  %>
  </div>

  <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="col-md-3">Batch no</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-md-3">Date in</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-md-3">Expected retirement date</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-md-3">Flock type</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-md-3">Source</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-md-3">Flock stored</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-md-3">Initial stock</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-md-3">Current stock</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-md-3">Left stock</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-md-3">Age</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-md-3">Notes</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-md-3">Status</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @flocks.each do |flock| %>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><%= flock.batch_no %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= flock.date_in %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= flock.expected_retirement_date %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= flock.flock_type %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= flock.source %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= flock.flock_stored %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= flock.initial_stock %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= flock.current_stock %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= flock.left_stock %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= flock.age %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= flock.notes %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= flock.status.name %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', [@status], class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success' %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_status_flock_path(@status, flock), class: 'btn btn-sm btn-secondary' %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [@status, flock], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger' %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have a sidebar partial, that has menu links, one of the links points to the "flocks index view". The Error comes when I try to access the "Flocks Index view", from this sidebar partial, here is the code of the sidebar:

**Sidebar partial code**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>

  <div class="d-grid">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block mx-2" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#offcanvasExample" role="button" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
      Menu
    </a>
  </div>


  <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasExample" aria-labelledby="offcanvasExampleLabel">
    <div class="offcanvas-header">
      <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="offcanvas-body">
      <%= link_to "Dashboard", dashboard_path, class: 'list-group-item' %>
      **<%= link_to "Flocks", status_flocks_path([@status, @flock]), class: 'list-group-item' %>**
      <%= link_to "Income", incomes_path, class: 'list-group-item' %>
      <%= link_to "Expenses", expenses_path, class: 'list-group-item' %>
      <div class="dropdown mt-3 d-grid">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block list-group-item" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
         Tools
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/statuses">Status</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/production">Type</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown mt-3 d-grid">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block list-group-item" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
         Reports
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/financial">Financial Report</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/production">Production Report</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need the `@flock` argument to `status_flocks_path`, instead it should just be `status_flocks_path(@status)`.

Comment: When I do that I get this error: 
`No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"flocks", :status_id=>""}, missing required keys: [:status_id]`

Comment: check now, removed the array wrapping argument

Comment: I get this error when I remove the array wrapping: 
`No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"flocks", :status_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:status_id]`

Comment: This means that you don't have a `@status` to create the link. If the sidebar is always displayed, you should only display that specific link when you have `@status`.

Comment: By the way, there is no "flocks index view" because it is a nested resource. You need to have a status instance to list flocks.